# Keep math notes (using mathjax or latex) online?

Tags: self-learning

Is there a way to store my own math notes online that can be marked up with either latex or mathjax?

Comment: [Overleaf](http://overleaf.com/) is a good tool.

Comment: So is [zettlr](https://www.zettlr.com/) backed up to Dropbox (which is what I do)

Comment: If you're thinking about blogging, wordpress has a package QuickLaTeX for this.